# MemberNotNullWhen does not trigger CS8775 (Member 'X' must have a non-null value when exiting with 'Y')

Tags: c#, nullable

Let's imagine the following code:

```
public class Test
{
    public string? Foo { get; set; }
    public string? Bar { get; set; }

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(this.Foo), nameof(this.Bar))]
    public bool IsInitialized => this.Foo != null;
}
```

I would expect this code to trigger a:

> CS8775 Member 'Bar' must have a non-null value when exiting with 'true'

If I rewrite the code like this:

```
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(this.Foo), nameof(this.Bar))]
    public bool IsInitialized
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Foo != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get the expected warning.

Is there something I am missing or this isn't the expected behavior?

Comment: Sound like a compiler bug to me. Reported issue [@github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/70398), will see what the smarter people will tell =)